# Place floating element at the bottom of its parent

Tags: html, css

Tie floats up to bottom, while keeping its participation in layout:

[image]

The way I go:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="yellow_block_one"></div>
    <div id="yellow_block_two"></div>
    <p>Content to fill and flow around</p>
</div>
```

Saw similar questions here, but no solution.
So what I have already got:

[image]

Here is the actual code that forms this screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/bmo25tx6/

And snippet:

```css
#i_am_main_container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 100, .5);
}
#i_am_sandbag_pusher {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.i_am_sandbag {
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="i_am_main_container">
    <div id="i_am_sandbag_pusher">I AM HERE TO PUSH IT DOWN</div>
    <div class="i_am_sandbag" style="width: 125px">I AM HERE</div>
    <div class="i_am_sandbag" style="width: 250px">TO MAKE IT FLOW AROUND</div>
    <h1>I'M THE HEADER 1</h1>
    <p>I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum!</p>
</div>
```

But it works only in Chrome and works very weird. For instance the whole layout fails if you remove the header.

Haven't found solution using javascript so far either.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a little I came to sort of solution.

Perhaps you may achieve desired effect with javascript:

```
var h = document.getElementById("i_am_main_container").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("i_am_sandbag_pusher").style.height = h + "px";
```

Comment: It looks attractive, but it won't guarantee correct behaviour in the general case, because you change text layout and you can't be sure text will fit correctly within the same height afterwards.

Comment: @jevgenij I agree with that remark (that's why it is "sort of solution"). Perhaps more than one iteration needed for nice looking result. P.S. No, I think second iteration will not help as height is at least initial div height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#i_am_main_container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 100, .5);
}
#i_am_sandbag_pusher {
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.i_am_sandbag {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="i_am_main_container">
    <div id="i_am_sandbag_pusher">
<div class="i_am_sandbag" style="width: 125px">I AM HERE</div>
    <div class="i_am_sandbag" style="width: 250px">TO MAKE IT FLOW AROUND</div>I AM HERE TO PUSH IT DOWN</div>
    
    <h1>I'M THE HEADER 1</h1>
    <p>I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum! I'm the Lorem Ipsum!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not shure about the point was attempted to formulate here, but for me it seems not to work either.